# How to speed up search while parsing a CSV file in Jquery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, performance, parsing

I have a CSV File with around 40K entries and 3 columns - Value, City and Class

The following is the structure:

```
Value    Class    City
111      lev 0    New York
112      lev 1    Winston
113      lev 2    Dakota
114      lev 2    Washington
```

Class lev-0 is parent for level-1 which is a parent for lev-2 (lev-0>lev-1>lev-2)

Now I have 3 select boxes Parent Region, Child Region, Sub-Child Region

I set an onchange listener for parent region where the selected value is returned and then searched through the CSV file and once matched all the elements below it with class = lev-1 are used to create a options list for the select box child region using a while loop until the class = lev-0 is where the loop stops.

The issue is that once I select an element, it takes around 3-4 seconds before the select box is filled and at many times it even hangs the browser.

I am using Papa Parser to parse the CSV

```
const csv = "https://example.com/locations.csv";
let results = [];
const csvData = Papa.parse(csv, {
  header: true,
  download: true,
  complete: response => {
    results = response.data;
  }
});
```

The following are functions to get the Class Name and City Name using value as input

```
function findCityByName(inputVal) {
  return results.filter(data => data.Value == inputVal)[0].City;
  }
function findClassbyValue(inputVal) {
  return results.filter(data => data.Value == inputVal)[0].Class;
  }
```

The following is the code to create option values for the select box Child Region

```
function GetChildRegions(inputVal){
var inputVal2 = inputVal;
var currentObject = results.filter(data => data.Value == inputVal2)[0];
currentIndex = results.indexOf(currentObject);
//move to next object
currentObject =  results.filter(data => data)[currentIndex + 1];
currentClass = findClassbyValue(currentObject.Value);
var RegionDropOption;

while (currentClass != 'level-0') {
  
  if(currentClass == 'level-1'){
  RegionDropOption += '<option value="' + currentObject.Value + '">' + currentObject.City + '</option>\n';
  currentIndex = results.indexOf(currentObject);
  currentIndex++;
  currentObject = results.filter(data => data)[currentIndex];
  currentClass = findClassbyValue(currentObject.Value);
  }
}
return RegionDropOption;
}
```

The following is the jquery to inject the html code in Child Region Select Box on change event of Parent Region

```
jQuery("#Parent_region").change(function() {
var selectedMainRegion = jQuery('#Parent_region').find(":selected").val();
jQuery("#child_region").html(GetChildRegions(selectedMainRegion));  

});
```

How to make the search faster?

**EDIT :**

**Adding Caching(Memoization)**

Momoizer Function

```
function memoizer(fun){
    let cache = {}
    return function (n){
        if (cache[n] != undefined ) {
          return cache[n]
        } else {
        console.log(n);
          **let result = fun(n)  // Result is Undefined here** 
          cache[n] = result
          return result
        }
    }
}
```

Funtion which was memoized.

```
function GetSubRegion(selectedMainRegion){
if (typeof(subRegWorker) != "undefined") {
subRegWorker.terminate();
}
subRegWorker = new Worker("subRegWorker.js");
subRegWorker.onmessage = function(e) {
var workData = e.data;
jQuery("#_sub_region").html(workData);
subRegWorker.terminate();
return workData;
}
subRegWorker.postMessage(selectedMainRegion);
}
```

example - var hello = GetSubRegion(123);
hello is undefined here. How to solve that ?

Call to the Memoized Function On Change

```
jQuery("#_main_region").change(function() {
var getCacheSub = memoizer(GetSubRegion);
var inputMainRegion = jQuery('#_main_region').find(":selected").val();
getCacheSub(inputMainRegion);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

js is single thread. this long loops are blocks computer. you need is worker.
workers are use another thread. example

```java
// main code
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) { // check for browserr support
    var work = new Worker("http://localhost:5500/worker.js") // you need another js file for worker
    work.postMessage("message") // send any data
    work.addEventListener("wessage",function(e){
        console.log(e.data) // response of worker
    })
}

// worker file

self.postMessage("message"); // worker to main communicating 

self.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
console.log("Message from parent:", event.data); // main to worker communicating
});
```

if you don't wanna make second file.
https://github.com/keithwhor/multithread.js

translate by yourself

```java
// worker
/**
 * optimized class
 * logic is save the answer. for to be faster next time.
 * @param {array} results
 * @constructor
 */
class csvParseOpti {
    constructor() {
        this.caches = []; // cache response for optimization.
        //  ex. caches:[{City:{inpVal:"Ankara",res:"0"},Class:blabal}]
        this.results; // parsed csv by Papa
        /** [
         {City: "Ankara", Class: "1", Value: 111},
         {City: "Mersin", Class: "1", Value: 112},
         {City: "İzmir", Class: "0", Value: 113}
         ] temp table
         */
        this.talkWidthMain();
    }

    /**
     * write talkWidthMain part for this function
     * @parm {string} csv
     */
    runPapa(csv) {
        let results = [];
        Papa.parse(csv, {
            header: true,
            download: true,
            worker: true,
            fastMode: true,
            complete: response => {
                results = response.data;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }

    /*
    * talk width main thread
    * */
    talkWidthMain() {
        self.addEventListener("message", (msg) => { // listen main
            console.log(msg)
            if (msg.data.func == "city") { // eğer ana çekidekden gelen mesaj da city varsa findCityByName()'i çalıştır
                self.postMessage(this.findCityByName(msg.data.value)); // komutun çıktısın döndür.
                // eğer istersen idde gönderebilirsin. cavpalrın karışmaması için.
            } // else diyer fonkisyonlar için aynısı
        })
    }


    /**
     * search in cache if not exist finds in array and push in cache.
     * do this for anothe functions
     * @param {string} inpVal
     * @public
     * @return {string}
     * */
    findCityByName(inpVal) { // your find function
        let cache = this.caches.filter(cache => cache.City.inpVal == inpVal); // check if this is used before
        if (cache && cache.length > 0) { // if is used return end of this function
            return cache[0].City.res;
        }
        // Not: if cache.City an cache.Class leangth's sum ara same as len of result. set null cahe
        cache = this.results.filter(data => data.City == inpVal)//[0].City; // else find in big array
        this.caches.push({City: {inpVal, res: cache}}); // and push in to caches
        return cache; // vala
    }
}

new csvParseOpti();
// main 
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) { // check for browserr support
    var work = new Worker("opt.js") // you need another js file for worker
    work.postMessage({func:"city",value:"Mersin"}) // send any data
    work.addEventListener("message",function(e){
        console.log(e) // response of worker
    })
}
```

this is just caches the response.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Workers solve the problem of browser page crashing but the search time is still 2-3 seconds. Is there anyway I can fasten up the search or any way to improve the above search loop to increase the search speed ?

Comment: could you do debug your code with console.time? which part is take long time. papa is to supports worker and have fast mode. read the docs.https://www.papaparse.com/docs

Comment: I added the worker and fast tag to papa parse. 

I checked with console.time and Papa Parse just takes around 150ms to download and parse the document. The while loop itself takes on an average 3000 ms to complete. I placed the timer inside the loop and each loop cycle takes on average 3ms to complete. 

Is there a way to reduce that ?

Comment: can you send me the csv

Comment: did you use cache?

Comment: I tried to add caching but I am facing an issue. I have added the code in my question above. The cached value is not stored because the function `code`GetSubRegion(selectedMainRegion)`code` does not return a value because it contains a worker.onmessage where the value is returned but I am not able to figure out how to make the parent function return the value. Please have a look at the code I have updated above and lemme know if you can suggest some fix for it.

Comment: is worker finish the job ? I meant find and subregion result save to cache.
why you don't use server or firebase?

Comment: I am not a very experienced developer. This is a wordpress website and am just using JS/jQuery to add features. The caching function works fine to send a call to GetSubRegion(selectedMainRegion) function using the following statement in the memorization function - let result = fun(n)  but as the function doesn't result any value, result variable is undefined and it couldn't be stored in cache.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @eay to guide to utlise workers and memoization

The caching issue was solved as follows -

```
    var cache = {};
    function memoizer(fun){
        
        return function (n){
            if (cache[n] != undefined ) {
            jQuery("#_sub_region").html(cache[n]);  // This was changed
            return cache[n]
            } else {
            console.log(n);
              cache[n] = result
              return result
            }
        }
    }
```

```
function GetSubRegion(selectedMainRegion){
if (typeof(subRegWorker) != "undefined") {
subRegWorker.terminate();
}
subRegWorker = new Worker("subRegWorker.js");
subRegWorker.onmessage = function(e) {
var workData = e.data;
cache[n] = workData // This was changed
jQuery("#_sub_region").html(workData);
subRegWorker.terminate();
return workData;
}
subRegWorker.postMessage(selectedMainRegion);
}
```